# Looping through a dataset in a VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of data in column A on worksheet "November", I'm trying to make a loop that will extract one cell at a time, input it in another worksheet "Generator" Cell.D15 run a simple macro to save the worksheet into PDF and then loop back.

My PDF macro works fine but I'm having trouble with the loop process.

Comment: May we see your current code, or the relevant part of it, edited into your question? Code formatting tools are available in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand but if you simply want to Loop it I guess something like this would work:

```
Sub Transfer()

Dim i As Integer
Dim Rows As Integer

    Rows = Worksheets("November").Range("A2", Worksheets("November").Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    For i = 1 To Rows

        Worksheets("Generators").Range("D15") = Worksheets("November").Cells(i + 1, 1)

        PDF_Create()

    Next

End Sub
```

In this example Code You would have a Title in A1 and then the data begins in A2 with no blank Values. It will then Change the number in D15 accordingly and then you can input your PDF_Create Function.